# Como escribir texto con response

Tags: asp, vb6

Estoy trabajando con Asp clásico y no puedo escribir con `Response.Write` muestro el código.

```
<%@ Language="javascript" %>
<html>
<body>
<form>

    <h3>Hello world!!! This is an ASP page.</h3>

    <% Response.Write("This content was generated ");%>
    <% Response.Write("as part of an execution block");%>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Por otro lado como pruebo ese código no se puede abrir en el explorador web se abrió en el IDE de visual Basic 6.0, ¿como puedo probarlo en el explorador web?, necesito implementar algo. En el fondo intento programar vb6 con asp clásico.

Comment: Mi hermano @pedro prueba asi :

<%
Response.Write "Hola Mundo"
%>

Comment: Hola Pedro tal vez no entiendo pero me parece que tu pregunta es que deseas saber como pruebas en el browser?ç

Comment: @Jorgesys Así es, el vb6 que papel tendría para tomar datos de la pagina nada más? primera vez que voy a trabajar vb6 con web, solo lo había usado en escritorio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se realiza en ASP clasico de esta forma:

```
<%Response.Write "este es mi mensaje"%>
```

o puedes contener el texto dentro de `( )`

```
<%Response.Write("este es mi mensaje")%>
```

---

```
<html>
<body>
<form>

    <h3>Hello world!!! This is an ASP page.</h3>

    <% Response.Write "This content was generated "%>
    <% Response.Write "as part of an execution block"%>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**El archivo obviamente debe tener la extensión .asp** y debe poder ser identificado como tal por el IIS.

Comment: Jorgesys, tienes razón active el IIS en el Windows 7 que estoy trabajando puse los archivos .asp en la carpeta inetput y funciono a la perfección. El tema es que voy a trabajar con vb6 con ASP(Active Server Pages) clásico el lenguaje por defecto VBScript `<%%>` el código debe ir entre esas etiquetas. Para dar mantenimiento a una pagina asp que IDE debo usar sera con el ID DE vb6.0? con un block de notas me daría terror.

Comment: Jorgesys, segun un manual que encontré tenía que instalar PWS Personal Web Server pero eso se usa en Windows 98 y yo estoy usando Windows 7 no me quedo de otra de activar el IIS y funciona a la perfección.

Comment: @Pedroavila Hola Perdro puedes crear tu archivo con cualquier editor html (he usado aptana), yo uso generalmente el mismo visual studio para esto. Me hiciste un flashback con el Personal Web Server hahaha! :P . Exacto solo correr el IIS y asegurar pueda resolver asp's.

Comment: Hola trabajo con Sublime Text, acabo de instalar aptana se ve interesante, cuando dices visual studio no te refieres a vb6 verdad.

Comment: Sublime text también lo he usado (actualmente me parece que es el mas comun :0 ). Me refiero en el que puedes crear .aspx , pero puede funcionar como editor de .asp